# Parse JSON with variable key in retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I'm working on an application with the retrofit library but I'm not in charge of the backend.

This is the JSON I receive when there is an error.
For example when the parameter 'email' is wrong I get this as JSON response:

```
{"status":"error","errors":{"email":{"emailNotFound":"Email not found"}}}
```

Now the 'email' part is the parameter that is wrong.  How do I make an object for this that I can reuse for multiple parameters.

I have this:

```
public class AuthenticateResponse {

@Expose
private String status;
@Expose
private Error errors;
@Expose
private String session;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getSession() {
    return session;
}

public void setSession(String session) {
    this.session = session;
}

public Error getErrors() {
    return errors;
}

public void setErrors(Error errors) {
    this.errors = errors;
}
}
```

But I don't know how to make my Error object because the key is variable. In this case it's 'email' but it's always different.

I have this

```
public class Errors {
private List<Object> list;

public List<Object> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(List<Object> list) {
    this.list = list;
}
}
```

But 'list' is not a key in the json so this doesn't work.
Any solutions ?

Comment: try it with a simple hashmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. You can register a type adapter in retrofit like this :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Errors.class, new ErrorAdapter())
                .create();
```

Than pass that converter to RestAdapter

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
                .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
                .build();
```

And in the ErrorAdapter I parse the JSON manually

```
public static class ErrorAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<Errors> {
    @Override
    public Errors deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Errors errors = new Errors();

        try {
            if (json != null) {
                JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();

                for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> elementJson : jsonObject.entrySet()) {
                    JsonObject error = elementJson.getValue().getAsJsonObject();
                    String errorValue = error.entrySet().iterator().next().getKey();

                    errors.addError(errorValue);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            errors = null;
        }
        return errors;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make response class like this:

```
public class EmailReponse{

    public String status;
    public MError errors;

    public static class MError{
          public HashMap<String, String> email;
    }

 }
```

with this response you can get email objects like a HashMap.
Wish this help you!